# What is the difference between 武道 and 格闘技?

Tags: word-choice

When I was looking through the Category List on OKWAVE, I found these two listed under the スポーツ・フィットネス (Sports and Fitness) sub-category.

When I looked them up on Weblio, I found that both [武道](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E6%AD%A6%E9%81%93) and [格闘技](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E6%A0%BC%E9%97%98%E6%8A%80) could be translated as “martial arts”.

Is there a difference between these two terms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

格闘技 is skills to fight with enemies. 武道 has mentality related to the code of samurai in addition to the skills. For example, boxing is 格闘技 but not 武道.

Not only the skills but also cultivating own character is important in 武道. 柔道,  剣道, 弓道, 相撲, 空手道, 合気道, 少林寺拳法, なぎなた, 銃剣道 affiliated with Japan Budo Association.

Comment: Hey, thanks for that! I also found this: https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1421824129. It seems that the former in my question is focused on self-defence, whereas the latter is focused on competing against an opponent to see which one is stronger.